# Passing dynamic array: blanks out values

Tags: arrays, vba

In VBA, I am storing values into a dynamic array called `PidArr` in a function called `Unlock`. The array starts like:

```
Dim PidArr() As String
ReDim PidArr(1 To 2)
```

The data getting inserted looks like:

```
      ...within a loop
        PidArr(Count) = LineStr 'this is a string containing the data.
        Logging "Inserted " & PidArr(Count) 'this correctly shows the data has inserted.
        ReDim PidArr(1 To Count + 1) 'resize the array more
```

After correctly storing values into that array, another function (Advance) is later called (and passes the `PidArr` array into it)

```
Advance listRecords:=PidArr
```

The function looks like:

```
Sub Advance(ByRef listRecords() As String)
```

In `Advance` I can print something like:

```
UBound(listRecords)
```

And it returns a 6.

But when I try to print out the values like `listRecords(1)` or `listRecords(2)` etc, nothing gets printed out (blank).

Why is this? It doesn't crash, so it's not an invalid range in the array at all.

Comment: you'll have to show us the relevant code.  Like where it gets filled, where it gets passed in and whats in the Advance subroutine.

Comment: And what application is this VBA hosted in?

Comment: @RBarryYoung BostonWorkStation

Comment: I added the code that fill code. Where it gets passed should already be there. The Advance subroutine only tries to print out the array values to make sure it works, which is shown already.

Comment: We need to see how the array gets from the loading code to the line that passes it into the Advance subroutine.  Is it in the same routine? the same module? is it being passed from on to the other before Advance? and is there any other access to the array in-between?  We cannot check for these things if you do not show us the code or tell us how these elements are related.  We also need to see how you are trying to print it.  We can only help you with what you show us and so far that's not a lot.

Comment: Wait, MGZero got it in the code you just posted ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use need to `redim preserve`.  What you've done by just using redim is redimensioned (redeclared) the array with a new size and truncated the old data.  So you just have elements sitting there with nothing in them.  `preserve` will hold onto the data in the elements when you `redim`.